# Getting PHP registration form to connect with MYSQL

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm about to yank my hair out of my head over this. I'm building a test site and my test form seems to work well, but when I submit my form it says "cannot find page". It's probably something dumb, but what am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
$db =connect('jsnow_jsnow','missysnow2005');
if($db!=false)
{
   register($db);
   echo "User registered";
} 

}

function connect($dbuser,$dbpassword)
{
    try{
        $db = new  PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jsnow_login',$dbuser,$dbpassword);
        return $db;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e;
        return false;}
}

function register($db)
{
    $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = sha1($_POST['password']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['e_mail']);

    $query = "INSERT INTO members(username,password,email) values('".$user."','".$password."','".$email."')";
    try{
        $db->eginTransaction();
        $db->exec($query);
        $db->commit();
        echo "commit succesful";
    }catch(Exception $e){}
}




?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost/jsnow_login/registration.php" method="post">
username:<input type="text" name="username"/>
password:<input type="password" name="password"/>
email<input type="text" name="e_mail"/>
<input type="submit"/>

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not sure what happened while copying but you have to slide to the right to see all the code

Comment: **registration/php** or **registration.php** ??

Comment: You're mixing PDO, `mysql_*` functions, using a URL as a DSN, and using a `/` instead of `.` in a URL. I suspect there's a lot of things going wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

`http://localhost/jsnow_login/registration/php` should probably be replaced with the string `http://localhost/jsnow_login/registration.php` where the `<form action=` is located at the bottom

and you're probably creating the PDO connection incorrectly.

example connections:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', 'password');

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

$dsn = 'uri:file:///usr/local/dbconnect';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
```

you will see an error like... *exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'* if your PDO connection is not set up right.  Put in the correct path to where the database is located, not the URL of the current page you're working on.

[PDO connection documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

and instead of using mysql_real_escape_string... since you're using PDO, you should bind your parameters to prevent sql injection:

```
$result_set = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `first_name`, `last_name`) 
                                VALUES (:username, :password, :first_name, :last_name)");
$result_set->execute(array(
    ':username' => $username, ':password' => $password,
    ':first_name' => $firstname, ':last_name' => $lastname
));
```

Comment: Thank You so much for the help It has gotten me so close. I am now connecting with the database but I am getting this Error
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/jsnow/public_html/registration.php on line 26

Comment: Still need help?  Update your post with the new code you're using and I can take a look.  Also: edit out your DB credentials when you post code online. Your error means... if this is your statement: `$pdo->prepare` then `$pdo` is not a PDO object.  Something went wrong with the connection.  [Read through this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) documentation about the PDO constructor and its parameters, what it returns and examples... It's probably an issue with the DSN you're providing.

Comment: ...and I can't help too much with that because it's specific to your stuff.